# Error after install SSL Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For the first time I see this message error after I put https in my codeigniter website.

```
Message: Call to undefined function iconv()

Filename: /home/admedica/public_html/admedicall_v1/application/views/admin/billing/bill/centro/bill.php

Line Number: 45

Backtrace:

File: /home/admedica/public_html/admedicall_v1/application/controllers/Admin.php
Line: 3981
Function: view

File: /home/admedica/public_html/admedicall_v1/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Before without https it works.

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you move it to a new server, or is the SSL version trying to run a different version of PHP.  It looks like the iconv library isn't installed with PHP.

Comment: No, i am still using the same server but I use the SSL provided by wordpress

Comment: The issue likely isn't with the SSL certificate, however does it start working again if you don't connect via HTTPS?

Comment: I have thoses codes in the page that show me the error : setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish'); and iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', strftime("%d %B %Y %X", strtotime($row->update_date))). When I remove them the page displays without the error

Comment: However with no https and with those codes the page works good as well